# What research that suggested non-additive effects are rare (in any domain) is Frank Harrell referring to here?

Tags: references, modeling

I've just read this remark from [Frank Harrell](https://www.fharrell.com/post/stat-ml/):

> AHRQ-sponsored research I did on large medical outcomes datasets in
> the 1990s with the amazing University of Nevada Reno
> physician-statistician Phil Goodman, whom we lost at an all-too-early
> age, demonstrated that important non-additive effects are rare when
> predicting patient mortality.

I've had a look round, but I can't find this research. Does anyone know what paper(s) might be referred to, or of other research suggesting non-additive effects are rare (in any domain)?

Comment: An interesting sidenote is that in social sciences people have been critical of the assumption of additivity. Effects can't be large and additive at the same time. See the [piranha problem](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2017/12/15/piranha-problem-social-psychology-behavioral-economics-button-pushing-model-science-eats/).

Comment: I am also interested in this, and to be honest quite skeptical. We found quite important gene-environment interactions in psychology. So, to be sure, this is not mortality, but I would assume that similar effects hold in mortality, especially for rare polymorphisms, but probably also for more common ones, though the signal is likely weaker there. Unless these interactions do not fall under "non-additive effects" in their taxonomy?

Comment: I can find only one joint publication (Cancer 1997;79(4):857-62) which has little to do with the remark and nothing with AHRQ, and the publication library from the latter only dates back to 2001. I'm assuming this is unpublished.

Comment: I vaguely recall a comment from Robyn Dawes from maybe the 90's saying that meaningful interactions were rare in the real world.  I see several things that hint in that direction on [his Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robyn_Dawes).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately we did not publish this.  Here's a summary.  We assembled 5 large medical databases with a binary mortality outcome.  For each we developed a then state-of-the-art neural network model and a logistic model.  The neural net did not add very much to any of the logistic models.  Delving deeper into this I allowed for each of the 5 datasets the presence of all two-way interactions among the model's variables.  None of the interactions in any of the 5 were important.

Since then I have continued to routinely quantify on lots of datasets, using methods similar to [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue), what proportion of the total predictive information is due to two-way interactions.  I typically find that additive effects explain more than 0.95 of the explainable log-likelihood.

Comment: +1 always benchmark complex models/classifiers against simpler ones (particularly logistic regression).  Papers are still being published on applications where logistic regression would have been found to outperform (deep) neural networks, had both been evaluated.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any intuition as to how rare two-way interactions are in non-medical domains?

Comment: @Mohan it may be that more data is required to identify the interactions, so not being able to exploit them does not mean that they are not there in the data generating process.  I have run into this in problems to do with predicting gene regulation where it is very likely that there are interactions between regulator proteins, but predictive performance doesn't necessarily increase very much if you include them (there are a *lot* of regulators, so the space of interactions is *huge*).

Comment: I can't speak to large scale genetic data but I can speak to the types of clinical datasets I discussed.  It's not a sample size problem in this non-high-dimensional world.  The main measure I use is the proportion of explainable log likelihood that is explained by non-additive effects.  That proportion has been surprisingly small.